# Instantiating Class Object without using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection

As far as I know, what I'm trying to do (Title) is impossible.
However, here are 3 small samples of code - The first one being what I have right now, the second being what I'd like to have, the third one being a way to achieve it that I don't want to use due to reflection. I'm wondering if there is a way to restructure my code to come closer to the second example.
There are a few assumptions made: Each class that will be used here has only one constructor, and knows exactly what objects it needs. The Object[] is because I don't know everything at runtime.

1.

```
Object o; Object[] params; String myString;
switch(myString){
case "ClassA": o = new ClassA(params);
case "ClassB": o = new ClassB(params);
//ETC
}
```

2.

```
Object o; Object[] params; String myString;
HashMap<String, Class<?>> map;
o = new map.get(myString)(params); //Obviously doesnt work
```

3.

```
Object o; Object[] params; String myString;
HashMap<String, Class<?>> map;
o = map.get(myString).getConstructors()[0].newInstance(params);
```

Note that I actually lied above. What I have right now is not `1`, but `3`. I can't have `1` because I can't hardcode all classnames. I'd like to have `2` though. Any suggestions?

Some clarifications:

The HashMap in examples `2` and `3` contains pairs of string representations of the classname, and actual class-objects.

Also, it is filled at runtime (Obviously), meaning that I know of all possible classes I would want to instantiate before executing the code above, however I can't hardcode any of them: They're loaded by file.

Comment: Why do you want it? What's in `map`?

Comment: Instantiating with reflection but without reflection use is ... complicated.

Comment: If you can't hardcode all classnames you also can't have `2` or where should all the strings come from? Or is it a misunderstanding and you at least know at one point in code about all the classes (ClassA, ClassB...) that are possibly used?

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz Reason I want to is a follow up question of this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42446144/patterns-be-independent-of-different-subclasses-by-passing-an-object-array-to-t   . Map holds pairs of Strings (Name of class) and the actual class.

Comment: @davidxxx But, is it possible? The thing is, I know *which* class I want to instantiate - But I can't hardcode it.

Comment: @MarkusBenko My code *loads* the classnames at runtime. Meaning that before this code is executed, I theoretically know about all class names I want to use. However: I don't know them while coding, so I can't hardcode it.

Comment: @user2065501 it was ironical. Having a class loadable from a classloader is a thing, instantiating it in the executed code without writing `new YourClass()` is another. Reflection or byte code manipulation is unavoidable if you don't instantiate explicitly the class in your compiled code.

Comment: Does `map.get(myString).newInstance();` work?

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz Yes. Edit: Well, no, since I don't have any default constructors in my classes. Or, rather, I don't want to have any default constructors, because I need values to be set.

Comment: @user2065501, does it solve your problem?

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz Sorry, I made a mistake. Edited my comment. But even if it worked, it'd just be the same as my version above. Which is reflection, and slow, and ugly, and totally not what I want to use.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz Nope, it doesn't, unfortunately. (See my edited comments. Sorry for that, I should just have posted new one's instead of editing the old ones)

Comment: You can use a wrapper class for your map. You can implement a custom `instantiate(String[] params)` method and then just `o = mapWrapper.get(myString).instantiate(params);`.

Comment: I'm not sure if making instances by newInstance would be extremely slow if you would keep reference to class. Regarding if it is ugly it is ugly, but try to encapsulate it somewhere where you will not look at it. If you really want to go crazy, you could do the following: instantiate only on the beginning, so called prototype object, then use prototype.clone() to create new objects of it, so you will only initially have warmup with reflection, and then clone is pretty fast. This solution is even worse in my opinion, because of possible errors, but it does instantiate class without reflection.

Comment: @GrzegorzGórkiewicz Well, the point is that I don't want to use reflection. Making a wrapper wouldn't solve anything.

Comment: @user2065501 You could also use java code manipulation at runtime that avoid reflection.

Comment: @Dexamit Right! I also thought about prototyping once, but thought that it may be too prone to copying errors. I also thought about adding an init method instead of a constructor to at least make some things a little easier, but then that would be too messy as well. I guess if I really really have to use reflection I'll do it, but then it'd be nice if I can somehow also get rid of my `Object[] params` thing, because that is also very ugly...

Comment: @davidxxx ... That's a thing? Wow, I didn't even know that. Isn't it also really ugly, though?

Comment: It is powerful but as lib that use it (hibernate, spring,  ejb, etc...) it hides things, so it increases complexity under the hood.

Comment: If you want to initialize a Class without reflection, perhaps you are just looking for a HashMap from String to Object with one Object being a Function that maps a HashMap of inputs to a HashMap representing your Object whose prototype is set to your parent HashMap. Alternatively you can just use Nashorn JavaScript that did that for you and likely comes with your installation of Java.

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry to inform:
it is not possible in Java.

Write your own language that does not follow the principle of bivalence, where you can instantiate a class with reflection but without use of reflection. Good luck.

Comment: Well, the wording was just to illustrate my problem. The actual question is how I could and should restructure my code to avoid reflection while allowing modular loading of entities.

Comment: I bet that is impossible. You could write your own tool that does it and host in in central Maven repository (to hide it).

Comment: I actually think that I may have found a possible way of restructuring my code, taking into account all the comments above: In a HashMap, I store the string-name of an entity and an "EntityFactory", which is a class that will return a new instance of that specific entity. Thus, adding new entities will be as easy as calling my "registering" method: `bla.registerEntity("EntityType", new EntityFactory(){@Override public Entity create(Object[] params){new EntityType((int)params[0]);}}`, for example. Thus, when I need an instance, having a name, I can simply: `map.get(name).create(params)` :)!

Comment: @user2065501, answer your own question.

Comment: I will once I know for sure that it works. Am currently implementing it, so that I can test it :)